# How can I unhighlight a highlighted line?

Tags: highlight, geany

If I do a particular kind of search, or if I just jump to a particular line, the target will be highlighted in a blazing yellow. How can I unhighlight a row that is highlighted like this? I don't mind the highlighting existing, but once I'm done jumping to line 420, I don't need it to stay highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yellow highlighting is a "marker". The only way I've found to remove a marker is to go to `Edit > Preferences > Keybindings`, add a keyboard shortcut to `Remove markers` (way down the list in the `Document` section), and then use that to remove it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The shortcut in question highlights the line in green and goes back to being yellow if I unhighlight.

Comment: That sounds like the `Toggle marker` shortcut. `Remove markers` clears any markers that have been set in the document (at least in Geany 1.36 on my machine). A key combination has to be assigned to `Remove markers`, though, because it doesn't have one assigned by default.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the key combination is the `Document` menu where you can find `Remove markers` near the end.

Comment: Great answer, thanks